# Send Email Button is Not working in a Managed Package that i have installed in Sandbox

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, managed-package, sandbox

I have created a managed package in a developer edition org that contains send email button. When I install the package in another test org(dev edition), everything works fine. But , when I install the same managed package in Sandbox every thing works perfect except send email button.
I am badly stuck in it. What could be the issue I am unable to debug

Answer (score 0):

Please check your email deliverability settings.

To send an email on sandbox, change the setting to "All Emails"

Here is the reference [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_sandbox_email_deliverability.htm&type=5):

Comment: I have changed system emails to All Emails , but it wont work @Tanuj